# Pig: optimal number of maps with a 4 node cluster?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera

I am using a hadoop `Cloudera` system with 4 nodes only, but a lot of disk space (**200TB**).

In my `pig` script, I load several monthly files that are about **200Gb** in size each.

I noticed that if I load in my pig script about one year of data, Pig creates about 15k `mappers` and the whole process takes approximately 3 hours (including the `reduce` step).

Instead, if I load three years of data (about **5TB**), then Pig creates about 30k `mappers` and basically all the nodes become unhealthy after processing for more than 15 hours.

Am I hitting some kind of bottleneck here? 
Or there is some default options I should play with? My pig script is very basic: I group by, I count.

Many thanks!

Comment: What is the memory of this nodes and the size you have set for each container

Comment: thank you Sachin! this is what I see from the hadoop server Total `Vmem allocated for Containers 252.00 GB`
`Vmem enforcement enabled false`
`Total Pmem allocated for Container 120 GB`
`Pmem enforcement enabled true`
`Total VCores allocated for Containers 16`
`NodeHealthyStatus true`

Comment: Can you also send the memory per container?Also looking at the above configuration it seems that it needs more mappers but due to the memory limitation you are not able to achieve that much of parallelism.Solution can be to increase the number of nodes which will spawn more containers or reduce memory per container this will also increase the number of container per node

Comment: thanks again. where can I see the memory per container? adding extra nodes is not feasible unfortunately. maybe there are alternative solutions?

Comment: you can see it in ambari as Map memory .Just hover the mouse and verify the property name.

Comment: i dont have access to ambari, only to the vanilla hadoop server where I can see my RUNNING/ACCEPTED/KILLED apps, and some other stuff

Comment: In the log for container blabla I see 
`stderr : Total file length is 2035 bytes.
stdout : Total file length is 0 bytes.
syslog : Total file length is 60854126 bytes.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be late to answer(better late than never), but let me share my ideas,

**1)Mapper and Reducer count setup**
Make sure you are allocating right amount of mapper and reducer slots for tasktraker nodes.
MapTask - mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum
ReduceTask - mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum
Example:
Let's say you have 4 node cluster with each node having 36 GB RAM, then let's assume each map/reduce task requires 4GB RAM. Giving 4GB for general purpose, we can assume that the remaining 32 GB will be 
used by the tasks(map/reduce). One task requiring 4GB, we would end up with 8 tasks(4Map, 4Reduce)

**2)Make full use of available RAM**
RAM allocation for each JVM - mapred.child.java.opts -Xmx3500M
Example:
Considering we have set the number of tasks on each task tracker based on the above example, then we can set max RAM size to 3500M for each task.

Based on these two options you can make the best performace out of your cluster. You might also need to look into io.sort.factor and io.sort.mb in case if you are dealing with more spill.

*In addition to above options,in case if multiple users are using the same cluster, it's better to make use of fair scheduler/fair pool to make sure a single user doesn't bring down the entire cluster.*